# Closing Material UI Dialog from child component triggers parent's Dialog to open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 Dialogs, one on outer scope (parent) and one as a child.

```
export default function App() {
  const [parentDialogOpen, setParentDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [childDialogOpen, setChildDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleParentClick = () => {
    setParentDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const handleChildClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setChildDialogOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dialog
        open={parentDialogOpen}
        onClose={() => setParentDialogOpen(false)}
      >
        <Box p={4}>Parent Dialog</Box>
      </Dialog>

      <Box bgcolor="red" p={2} onClick={handleParentClick}>
        <Dialog
          open={childDialogOpen}
          onClose={(e) => setChildDialogOpen(false)}
        >
          <Box p={2}>Child Dialog</Box>
        </Dialog>

        <button onClick={handleChildClick}>Child</button>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click on the button, it opens a dialog (Child Dialog), but when I close it, the Parent Dialog pops up. My expected behavior is that clicking on the child button should not fire `onClick` event on the parent (as I've added `e.stopPropagation()` to Child's `onClick` handler)

Adding `e.stopPropagation()` on `handleChildClick` does stop the event to propagate to Parent's `onClick`, but when I close the Dialog, Parent's `onClick` still fires.

I have also tried adding `e.stopPropagation()` to the Child Dialog's `onClose`, but it does not help.

Although moving the Child Dialog to the same level as Parent Dialog makes it work as expected, I cannot do that because in my (real) code I have to dynamically render the child component which the child component may have it's own Dialog.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

[UPDATE]: Seems like Parent Dialog's `onClick` event also fire when clicking ANYWHERE when Child Dialog is open. For example, clicking INSIDE child dialog will fire Parent Dialog's `onClick` (without closing Child Dialog)

Here is a Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/eloquent-hypatia-nuksu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `handleParentClick ` is not bound to parent dialogue it is bound to parent div of child dialogue. It is a natural behaviour it is triggered when you click anywhere in the child dialogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stop the propagation in the onClick event of the Dialog (see below)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Box, Dialog } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [parentDialogOpen, setParentDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [childDialogOpen, setChildDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleParentClick = () => {
    setParentDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const handleChildClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setChildDialogOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dialog
        open={parentDialogOpen}
        onClose={() => setParentDialogOpen(false)}
      >
        <Box p={4}>Parent Dialog</Box>
      </Dialog>

      <Box bgcolor="red" p={2} onClick={handleParentClick}>
        <Dialog
          open={childDialogOpen}
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          onClose={(e) => setChildDialogOpen(false)}
        >
          <Box p={2}>Child Dialog</Box>
        </Dialog>

        <button onClick={handleChildClick}>Child</button>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This does fix my problem. However, are there any other solutions where I don't need to add this `onClick` event at the child dialog? Otherwise every child dialog (which can be used elsewhere) always need to add this special `onClick` event, not the best scenario when working with a lot of components & team.

Comment: You can try something like that if you want to avoid the use of the onClick : https://codesandbox.io/s/white-flower-0m1vp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Moving Child Dialog out of the Parent container is not an option for me, since this will be rendered dynamically (as mentioned in the question). However, I will accept the first solution as an answer because this can we done by override all material-ui Dialog through muiTheme.

Answer (score 0):

if your aim is to trigger parent dialog open when child is closed you could go with the following;

```
...
...
 <Dialog
          open={childDialogOpen}
          onClose={(e) => {
            setChildDialogOpen(false);
            setParentDialogOpen(true);
            }}
        >
```

Then get rid of `handleParentClick` for good

Comment: My aim is to prevent parent dialog from opening when the child is closed.